# Find a possible $A$: $\| f^{(n+1)} \|_{[a,b]} \le A$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

$$\| f \|_{[a,b]} \le A$$

$$\| f \|_{[a,b]}=\int_a^b \lvert f(x) \lvert \ dx \le \int_a^b  \max_{[a,b]} \lvert f(x) \lvert dx= (b-a) \max_{[a,b]} \lvert f(x) \lvert=(b-a) \ M  $$

In this case: $$A=(b-a) \ M$$

So, if $$\| f \|_{[a,b]} \le (b-a) \ M$$

$$\| f^{(n+1)} \|_{[a,b]} \le (b-a) \  M$$

Where is my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: That is not correct. Your $M$ might change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Example: $f(x)=x^2$ for $x \in [0,1]$

We have $A=M=1$, but $f''(x)=2$